# Yii2 - Ignoring 'OR' condition when Null

Tags: php, yii2

I have this query which is working fine

```
$order_items= OrderItem::find()
->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name,'instructor_id'=>$model->instructor_name])
->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();
```

But when `$model->instructor_name` is empty or null, I am getting Null result. 
So I want to ignore when `instructor_id` is Null
when

`'instructor_id'=>$model->instructor_name or instructor_id'=> Null`

how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [andFilterWhere()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#andFilterWhere()-detail)

```
$order_items = OrderItem::find()
   ->where(['location_id' => $model->location_name])
   ->andFilterWhere(['instructor_id' => $model->instructor_name])
   ->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])
   ->all();
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: `$ref = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select([
                'ProductCode',
                'ProductNameFull',
                'ProductSpec',
                'ProductGroup',
                'CompanyCode',
                'CompanyName'
                ,'Price',
                'PurchasePrice'
            ])->from('Product')
            ->andFilterWhere(['CompanyCode' =>  $comp_ids])
            ->all(Yii::$app->sds);`

Comment: where company code is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
$order_items= OrderItem::find()
->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name,'instructor_id'=>$model->instructor_name])
->andWhere(['not', ['instructor_id' => null]])
->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();
```

---

**Or add the following**

```
  ->andWhere(['<>', 'instructor_id', null])
```

**Or**

```
 ->andWhere('instructor_id IS NOT NULL')
```